# Cocoa: while(index >= 0) continuing, even though index == -1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, while-loop

I've got the following code:

```
-(void)removeFilesWithPathIndices:(NSIndexSet*)indexSet {
    NSInteger index = [indexSet firstIndex];
    while(index >= 0) {
        [self removeFileWithPathIndex:index];
        index = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:index];
    }
}
```

Which should iterate through an NSIndexSet. However, the while loop does not stop, even though index = -1 according to

```
 NSLog(@"%d", index);
```

Anyone able to solve this mistery for me? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't assume `NSInteger` to be an `int`. In fact it's not. So, `%d` in

```
NSLog(@"%d", index);
```

is deceiving you if you compile in 64 bit mode. See [NSInteger](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000018-SW16) documentation.

You shouldn't have even assumed that `indexGreaterThanIndex` to return `-1`. 
The documentation explicitly says it returns `NSNotFound`. By following the documentation, you eventually find `NSNotFound` is `NSIntegerMax`, the maximal possible value in an `NSInteger`.  When `NSInteger` is `long` and casted into an `int`, his becomes `-1`. But it's an implementation detail, and you shouldn't rely on that. That's why they defined a symbolic constant `NSNotFound` to start with.

You should have followed what the documentation says, and write a code like

```
while(index != NSNotFound) {
    [self removeFileWithPathIndex:index];
    index = [indexSet indexGreaterThanIndex:index];
}
```

In a sense you shouldn't have even declared

```
NSInteger index;
```

because the indices in Foundation are all `NS`**U**`Integer`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to NSInteger after getting confused that index became -1 and I somehow thought that my problem was related to that... Anyhow, I definitely should've read the docs on this one, sorry guys x( The bad side of autocompletion :P
Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Deleting my answer as you've got my point and more - `NSNotFound` is `NSIntegerMax` though, not the maximum for `NSUInteger`. This is `LONG_MAX` on 64bit which then becomes `-1` for `printf()` due to `%d`.

Comment: Ah, good point. Corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

`indexGreatherThanIndex:` returns `NSNotFound` when there's nothing greater than the specified index. [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSIndexSet/indexGreaterThanIndex:)

`NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`, which is `>= 0`. [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html:)

Your `NSLog` statement is just giving you a deceptive result. Instead of:

```
while(index >= 0)
```

Use:

```
while(index != NSNotFound)
```